# JavaScript Font-Family issue in IE

Tags: javascript, fonts, internet-explorer-8

Can someone think of a reason that this wouldn't work in any version of IE? I have a drop down select menu for choosing the font family of an element, which calls a javascript function to change the font-family. Here is the html...

```
 <select id="selecth1FontFamily" name="selectFontFamily" onchange="updateh1family();">
                                  <option> Serif </option>
                                  <option> Arial </option>
                                  <option> Sans-Serif </option>                                  
                                  <option> Tahoma </option>
                                  <option> Verdana </option>
                                  <option> Lucida Sans Unicode </option>                               
                              </select>
```

And here is the JavaScript...

```
function updateh1family() {

        var selector = document.getElementById('selecth1FontFamily');
        var cssPreviewSpan = document.getElementById('h1FontFamily');

        cssPreviewSpan.innerHTML = selector.value;
        // also update the CSS preview

        var h1 = document.getElementById('liveh1')
        h1.style.fontFamily =  selector.value;
    }
```

This works to change the font family of the element in EVERY browser, minus the dreaded internet explorer. Any thoughts? I mean, it is a fairly straightforward function, I tried to think of other ways to go about it but I'm pretty much stuck. Thank you to all who read this!

Comment: I can't see anything fundamentally wrong. Can you narrow it down to where it doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: Strangely enough, there are no errors thrown. I even dug out the IE8 developer tools to debug and I get nothing. The font family just isn't changing. Strangest thing.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debugged the code you would see that selector.value returns nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="liveh1">Some text</h1>
  <select id="selecth1FontFamily" name="selectFontFamily" onchange="updateh1family();">
    <option> Serif </option>
    <option> Arial </option>
    <option> Sans-Serif </option>                                  
    <option> Tahoma </option>
    <option> Verdana </option>
    <option> Lucida Sans Unicode </option>                               
  </select>
    <script>
      function updateh1family() {
        var selector = document.getElementById('selecth1FontFamily');
        var family = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
        var h1 = document.getElementById('liveh1')
        h1.style.fontFamily = family;        
      }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/agoqu3)

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, thank you so much. I suppose I need to learn the true meaning of debugging code. I feel like such a noob. Thanks again.