# How to create a font selection bar in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a drop-down menu in which we can see all the available fonts and we can select any font of our choice. Also I want to create a font-color selection widget. There exists a large no of font-styles. I want to know how do i get all these fonts and how to create a widget using which user can select the color of his choice.

For creating font-selection drop-down menu, I have used list and for demo purpose, i added 3-4 font names and displaying them. Its working fine.
Google gave me the list of all font-names but writing down in html code isn't a good approach i think. 
I guess there should exist a js library for doing all this. Is there ?

Comment: This smells like you're trying to develop a rich text editor on some level. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You could have fun with google font api :P http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jukka K. Korpela is right, but regarding your question:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547788/javascript-font-family-issue-in-ie) should get you started on the selecting font family:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="liveh1">Some text</h1>
  <select id="selecth1FontFamily" name="selectFontFamily" onchange="updateh1family();">
    <option> Serif </option>
    <option> Arial </option>
    <option> Sans-Serif </option>                                  
    <option> Tahoma </option>
    <option> Verdana </option>
    <option> Lucida Sans Unicode </option>                               
  </select>
    <script>
      function updateh1family() {
        var selector = document.getElementById('selecth1FontFamily');
        var family = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
        var h1 = document.getElementById('liveh1')
        h1.style.fontFamily = family;        
      }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If it's important to see if the fonts are installed you can use [this](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/) to tool to check. 
And if it's ok to use flash you may use something like [font-detect-js](https://github.com/gabriel/font-detect-js) (they also have a [demo](http://font-detect.s3.amazonaws.com/edit.html?) but I didn't manage to get it to work in chrome).

And for color selector I would recomend using : [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/)

Hope it helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 8):

Probably overkill... but here is a font selector example I came up with using Google Font API and a [Document Fragment Builder](http://rlemon.github.com/FragBuilder.js/) script I wrote a while ago.

```
var FragBuilder = (function() {
    var applyStyles = function(element, style_object) {
        for (var prop in style_object) {
            element.style[prop] = style_object[prop];
        }
    };
    var generateFragmentFromJSON = function(json) {
        var tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        json.forEach(function(obj) {
            if (!('tagName' in obj) && 'textContent' in obj) {
                tree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj['textContent']));
            } else if ('tagName' in obj) {
                var el = document.createElement(obj.tagName);
                delete obj.tagName;
                for (part in obj) {
                    var val = obj[part];
                    switch (part) {
                    case ('textContent'):
                        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
                        break;
                    case ('style'):
                        applyStyles(el, val);
                        break;
                    case ('childNodes'):
                        el.appendChild(generateFragmentFromJSON(val));
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (part in el) {
                            el[part] = val;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tree.appendChild(el);
            } else {
                throw "Error: Malformed JSON Fragment";
            }
        });
        return tree;
    };
    var generateFragmentFromString = function(HTMLstring) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"),
            tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        div.innerHTML = HTMLstring;
        while (div.hasChildNodes()) {
            tree.appendChild(div.firstChild);
        }
        return tree;
    };
    return function(fragment) {
        if (typeof fragment === 'string') {
            return generateFragmentFromString(fragment);
        } else {
            return generateFragmentFromJSON(fragment);
        }
    };
}());

function jsonp(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function replacestyle(url) {
    if (!document.getElementById('style_tag')) {
        var style_tag = document.createElement('link');
        style_tag.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style_tag.id = 'style_tag';
        style_tag.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style_tag);
        replacestyle(url);
    }
    document.getElementById('style_tag').href = url;
}

function loadFonts(json) {
    var select_frag = [
        {
        'tagName': 'select',
        'id': 'font-selection',
        'childNodes': [
            {
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': 'default',
            'textContent': 'Default'}
        ]}
    ];
    json['items'].forEach(function(item) {
        var family_name = item.family,
            value = family_name.replace(/ /g, '+');

        if (item.variants.length > 0) {
            item.variants.forEach(function(variant) {
                value += ':' + variant;
            });
        }

        select_frag[0].childNodes.push({
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': value,
            'textContent': family_name
        });
    });

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(FragBuilder(select_frag));
    document.getElementById('font-selection').onchange = function(e) {
        var font = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
            name = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
        if (font === 'default') {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = 'inherit';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = name;
            replacestyle('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + font);
        }
    };
}

jsonp("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDBzzPRqWl2eU_pBMDr_8mo1TbJgDkgst4&sort=trending&callback=loadFonts");​
```

Here is the [Kitchen Sink](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/) example...

Comment: Very beautiful code. Easy to understand and adapt. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a jquery library for displaying all the google fonts in a drop-down list with instant preview. https://github.com/saadqbal/HiGoogleFonts.
It has two callback methods:

- **selectedCallback** - This event is triggered when a font is selected
  but not yet loaded.
- **loadedCallback** - This event is triggered when the font is loaded and
  is ready to be applied. This is where you should apply font to an
  element.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get all the available fonts—on IE, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/listfonts1.html

But it would hardly be a good idea to offer such a list in a control meant to let the user select his preferred font. The list would practically certainly contain menu fonts that would make no sense as text fonts, such as fantasy fonts, Wingdings fonts, Symbol, and fonts with odd character repertoires.

Any list of “all font names” is either bogus or just a list of all font names under some very specific conditions.

The best way to let the user select a font of his preference is that you do not set font family at all, letting browser settings (which are usually user-controllable) take their full effect. There are good reasons for not doing that, though (such as Times New Roman being the most common factory default and most users not being interested in changing font settings in browsers).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jukka for your valuable advice. Actually I need this so that user can submit his comment or message in his preferred font but I got your point..anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @blunderboy, to get the comments in the user’s preferred font, I think you more or less need to ask for submissions as PDF files, with instructions telling them to write them in their favorite word processor and save as PDF. And you would need to hope that the word processors have such a feature and that it uses font embedding by default.