# font dialog button in CSS

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, vb.net

Is there any code like the font dialog box in vb.net that can use in PHP?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   If FontDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
      RichTextBox1.ForeColor = FontDialog1.Color
      RichTextBox1.Font = FontDialog1.Font
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you are looking for a windows control.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225816/how-to-create-a-font-selection-bar-in-html

Comment: i am trying to make an ID printing system, that the user can edit the font style of their ID form,